# How to change Serilog field name posted to Elastic Search

Tags: asp.net-core, elasticsearch, serilog, elk, serilog-sinks-elasticsearch

I have gotten my serilog elastic search sink working. My problem now is I am looking for a way to override or remove the default out of the box fields naming convention when logs are posted to elastic search.

Sample in my code.

```
Log.Information("{sTest} {sName} , "This is test.", "This is my name");
```

The one that will be created will have something like
`fields.sTest`, `fields.sName`

Is there a way to ommit the "fields." prefix and just use the `sTest` and the `sName`?
Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the `InlineFields` property to `true`.

```
var loggerConfig = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"))
    {
        InlineFields = true,
        ...
    });
```